# How to check if GRUB is in EFI or BIOS mode?

Tags: grub2, bios

Is there a command at the grub shell that would indicate if the machine is presenting EFI or BIOS firmware?

I'm using GRUB 2.00 on a 2010 Mac Pro. This computer has EFI firmware of course.  But I have been trying for a couple of days to get it to boot Ubuntu in BIOS-emulation mode for want of NVIDIA display drivers. My understanding is that by the time GRUB is running, the decision to use EFI or BIOS emulation has already been made.  So how can I check from GRUB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of GRUB 2.00, assuming GRUB is working well enough to get into normal mode rather than rescue mode, `echo $grub_platform` from the GRUB shell will show `pc` in BIOS mode and `efi` in UEFI mode.

The BIOS build corresponds to the `grub-pc` package, and the UEFI build corresponds to the `grub-efi-amd64` (or, less commonly, `grub-efi-ia32`) package.

Comment: Thank you.  I just tried it out straight from the Live CD (on USB) and got "efi". This is a good diagnostic because my understanding is that Ubuntu is not going to be loaded in BIOS mode following this indication.  Now to figure out how to get "pc"...

There may be a little wiggle room here.  I see the documentation for grub_platform says it indicates the platform for which GRUB was built.  It seems likely the ideas are equivalent to me, but I'm not an expert here.  I don't think the "efi" build of GRUB would even run in BIOS mode, right?

Comment: Correct; each build of GRUB uses firmware calls specific to the platform's firmware type.  To boot a live USB stick in BIOS mode, you'll need to hunt for a suitable firmware-level option; on a Mac it might perhaps involve Boot Camp, but it's been ages since I looked at one of those.  Note that when booting a live Ubuntu image (as opposed to an installed system) in BIOS mode you'll actually get ISOLINUX rather than GRUB.

Comment: How can I use an if statement with this? I have tried `if [ ${$grub_platform} == "pc" ] { ... }`, but it didn't work - it always evaluated to true.

Comment: That syntax is wrong in a couple of ways.  `if [ ${grub_platform} == "pc" ]; then ...; fi` is more likely to work.

Answer (score 1):

Grub2 implements shell-like syntax. This will work:

```sh
if test "${grub_platform}" = "pc"; then
  menuentry 'XYZ' {
    linux ${linux_params}
    initrd ${initrd_params}
  }
else
  menuentry 'XYZ' {
    linuxefi ${linux_params}
    initrdefi ${initrd_params}
  }
fi

# as well as
if [ "${grub_platform}" = "pc" ] ; then
fi

# or
if [ "${grub_platform}" = "pc" ]
then
fi
```