# How to install a dual-boot Ubuntu in BIOS mode and Mac OS X?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, mac

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in BIOS emulation mode, not the native EFI firmware, on my Mac Pro (2010).  I'm doing NVIDIA CUDA / OpenCL development and I require the NVIDIA proprietary graphics drivers.  There is pretty universal consensus around the web that the NVIDIA proprietary drivers will not run in EFI mode.

I have not been able to get to that BIOS emulation mode condition.

The most clear-cut installation method I have tried is to install without GRUB using `ubiquity -b` from the Live CD in combination with rEFInd.  This installation is very smooth, but the resulting Ubuntu install is running in EFI mode.

An alternative I have tried is to install without `-b` and to install the boot loader to a different partition on the same drive.  This time, my machine first boots to the GRUB menu, and correctly starts Ubuntu 13.10, but it starts in EFI mode.  (Evidenced by `ls /sys/firmware/efi` )

I have confirmed that the hard drive is partitioned with hybrid-MBR, and the GRUB2 partition is marked as bootable on the MBR.  (using `gdisk /dev/sdb`)

I'm not sure about this, but I am wondering if the Ubuntu installer is installing an EFI version of GRUB instead of a BIOS version, because the Ubuntu installer is running in EFI mode.  If this is the case, how can one start the installer from the Live CD in BIOS mode?

I have this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399732/how-to-check-if-grub-is-in-efi-or-bios-mode) regarding, is the BIOS-emulation vs EFI decision made before, during, or after the GRUB boot loader?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get Ubuntu booting in BIOS mode following experimentation with manual GRUB installation. Subsequent to that, my NVIDIA drivers worked.

The key factor is that `grub-install` will either install a BIOS or EFI version based on factors I don't understand. More importantly, I was not able to find an option that forces the BIOS version to be installed from an EFI machine. (The `--target=i386-pc` option was not working for me.) I found a special case: when running the Ubuntu Live CD on a Mac, `grub-install` installs a BIOS version not EFI, even though the Live CD is booted in EFI mode.

Sketch of the procedure:

1. Partition hard drive in Mac Disk Utility, making at least two partitions for Ubuntu. 1) a very small GRUB boot partition, and a partition for the root file system.  Format for the partitions can be anything, they will be changed later.
2. Boot the Live CD.  Start the installer from a terminal using `ubiquity -b`.
3. Run the custom installation "Something Else". When given the partition options, select the root partition and format it for linux, setting the `/` mount point.  Edit the the GRUB boot partition, changing the partition type to `BIOS Boot` -- and mark it `System Partition` and `Legacy BIOS Bootable`.
4. Complete the Ubuntu installation.  Do not reboot.
5. We'll install GRUB from Terminal in the Live CD session.  For whatever reason, this installs the BIOS GRUB. Terminal Commands: (sdX is the drive to install GRUB and the Ubuntu installation)

   ```
   $ sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt
   $ grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX
     Installation finished. No error reported.
   $ grub-install --root-directory=/mnt --recheck /dev/sdX
     Installation finished. No error reported.
   $ ls /mnt/boot/grub
     #the presence of the director i386-pc is a great sign.
   ```
6. Configuring the GRUB installation is a bit tricky.  We run it as though `/mnt` is the root filesystem.

   ```
   $ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   $ sudo chroot /mnt
   $ update-grub
   $ exit
   ```

   Running `grub-install` from the above context would install the EFI GRUB.  This explains the two steps.

   Note: If the above `update-grub` command fails due to executable not found then this procedure needs an adjustment. That indicates the initial condition for Step 5 is that the application package GRUB2 be installed on the target installation already. This procedure has not been tested straight through.
7. If all went well, you should be able to restart.  Hold down the option key, and you should a boot option presented by the Mac called `Windows`.  That should boot you into GRUB, which will be set up to boot the new Ubuntu installation.